# Textbox positioning issue on scroll when the position style is absolute

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I have a Asp:textbox on a page (the page have some different controls and div also)on which I am setting the style=position:absolute on event "onkeyup".
and increases its height dynamically according to Chartres entered into the textbox.but the problem is the position of text box always remain fixed when a user scrolls down or up the page." On event "onblur", i Changed the style=position=" ", but when the focus is on textbox it moves with the scroll up/down .
 here is code

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtComment1"  runat="server" Height="13px"  Width="99%" MaxLength="40" TextMode="MultiLine"   
     onkeyup="SetHeight(this)" onblur="Blur(this)"></asp:TextBox>

     <script type="text/javascript">

    //Setheight function is used to change the style of position:"Absolute"

    function Setheight(textscroll) {
        textscroll.style.height = "14px";
        textscroll.style.position = "absolute";
        textscroll.style.width = "49%";
    }

//Blur is used to again change the style position:""

 function Blur(txtdesc1) {


        txtdesc1.style.height = "14px";
        txtdesc1.style.position = "";
        txtdesc1.style.width = "99%";

    }

    </script>
```

P.S. : I have tried HoverMenuExtender but still having same problem

Comment: This is a 100% client-side problem. Show your actual HTML + CSS, not your .NET server-side code!

Comment: its not server side code , it a client side only.

Comment: <asp:TextBox> is not HTML, it's .NET, which is SERVER CODE!

Answer (score 0):

If you want an html item to follow the page down even on scroll, try position: fixed, that's how all of the stick headers and footers work on sites like LinkedIn and FB.

Comment: i dont want that my textbox will follow the scroll on page down and page up. i want it to be stable.